# Selector state pressed doesn't seem to be working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-viewholder

I have a RecyclerView that has a ImageView as it's ViewHolder. I'd like to add a white border around the ImageView that I clicked on. Since all those states are pretty confusing (pressed, selected, focused), all of them could mean the same thing, I'd like to ask for this specific case..

This is the adapter's ViewHolder xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.myproject.RoundRectCornerImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageHolder"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@drawable/image_details_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/thumbnail"
    android:focusable="true" />
```

And this is the selector I'm using:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#fff" />
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
    </shape>

</item>
```

So what I want to do here is, have a list of images in horizontal RecyclerView and if I click on one of those images, it will get this white border around itself, all the other ImageViews won't. I implemented onClick listener that loads the image in the background and it's working, but I can't get this selector to work like I want. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I see the problem here but let's clarify one case. If you have one checked item(with white border) and click on another one do you want that the first one become without border?

Comment: Yep! also, if my ImageView is 56x56 dp, should this selector also have size 56x56? or 58x58 for example if I set it's stroke width 2dp?

Comment: No matter. Selector used for background just like a color. So you have to specify padding for you imageview to make offset for src image inside imageview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to set your selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#fff" />
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_selected="false">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
    </shape>

</item>
```

Only selected will work in this case. Then you have to set the selection manually in your adapter's `getView()` method, like this:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(lastImageView != null)
                lastImageView.setSelected(false);
            lastImageView = (ImageView) view;
            lastImageView.setSelected(true);
        }
    });
```

And set this on the adapter as Global

```
private ImageView lastImageView = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added `android:state_selected="true"` in that scenario it is checking both the condition press effect as well as state. Remove state from your selector. Hope this will work for you.

Use below selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#fff" />
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
    </shape>

</item>
```

Comment: I did that because if I use only state_pressed, it just blinks.. When I click on ImageView, white borders just blinks, but if I long press on it, it stays until I release it.. That's why I was confused what actually means "pressed, selected, focused"..  So I tried with all of them, but with no luck..

Comment: You want it to only blink? Right?

Comment: No, I want it to stay white until I click on some other ImageView.. only selected ImageView should have white border

Comment: In that case do not use pressed effect. You need to manage it programmatically. If you are using recyclerview than either managing one more flag in your pojo class or if there is no recyclerView than you need to manage it by some individual flags only.

Comment: Ah, exactly what I wanted to avoid :)  But yeah, it makes sense.. At least I understadn those states well now :)  Thanks for your time anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this code :

```
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_pressed="true">
         <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#fff" />
           <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
    </shape>

</item>
```

Please check what you did in above code compare with this.

Comment: from your code just remove android:state_selected="true" line from first <item> block and 

from second <item> just keep it without any property of item for default 

and in last keep </selector>

Comment: Now I tried with state_pressed only, but when I click on ImageView, white border just blinks, but if I long click on it, white border stays until I release the click..

Comment: pressed: When user press the view then it this event occurred , selected: When user select any item like checkbox or radio button that time this event occurred ,

focused : When user get focused like Edit Text get focused to write something that time it's in focused mode that time this event occurred.

As above code when user press the view this event occurred when he release then it's default item will effect there.

Comment: That's what I thought :/  So there is no way to handle it this way? I should make my own logic inside the adapter, right?

Comment: You can use one any boolean flag inside your model and then you can set true when you clicked then need to make it selected background and others would be deselected.

If you have multiple selection allowed then use checkbox inside your item_layout of adapter and set above code with selected event set.

and use framlayout to make it proper layout looks.

Comment: Yep.. I wanted to avoid that, but now I see it's the only way :)  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually set the states for ImageView once click is detected.
RecyclerView doesn't store states for its child.